# Baffled by NSMutableArray sortUsingDescriptors: exception

Tags: ios, objective-c, sorting, nsmutablearray, nssortdescriptor

The following method:

```
- (NSMutableArray*) timeSortedBegins {
    NSMutableArray* begins = [self.spans valueForKey: @"begin"];
    NSSortDescriptor *sort = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey: @"cycleOffsetObject" ascending: YES];
    [begins sortUsingDescriptors: @[sort]];
    return begins;
}
```

throws this runtime exception:

```
2014-03-21 14:41:32.482 myValve[1741:60b] -[__NSArrayI sortUsingDescriptors:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x16d7bc20
2014-03-21 14:41:32.484 myValve[1741:60b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSArrayI sortUsingDescriptors:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x16d7bc20'
```

I have used breakpoints to convince myself that the `begins` array is indeed full of (two in this case) WEAnchor* objects. And that object implements the following two methods:

```
- (NSTimeInterval) cycleOffset {
    return self.offset + (self.datum ? self.datum.cycleOffset : 0.0);
}

- (NSNumber*) cycleOffsetObject {
    return [NSNumber numberWithDouble: self.cycleOffset];
}
```

To be honest, I only added the `cycleOffsetObject` wrapper method, because I thought maybe it couldn't work with non object values, I was using `initWithKey: @"cycleOffset"` before that. I have not declared these in the header file as a property, they're just accessor methods, not state. Is that the problem? If it is, how do you sort by the return value of a given selector? Or is it something head smackingly obvious that I'm just missing?

Comment: sortUsingDescriptor only works on a MUTABLE array.  (And just because the pointer says "Mutable" does not make the array mutable.)

Comment: BTW, the -1 is for not having Googled "unrecognized selector".

Comment: I actually did google the whole thing, and read a bunch of things. My real error was assuming that it was something about the `@"cycleOffset" and I totally glossed over that it was an `__NSArrayI`. Well actually, I did even notice that, but the toll free bridging/class cluster stuff that all the time, so I'm often not sure what I really have. I think I liked at the non-serif `I', thought it was an 'l' and maybe stood for List or something.

Comment: But that's the main point of "unrecognized selector" -- the object type is almost always wrong.  Had you studied any of the references you would have seen this.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As @dtrotzjr says, it sounds like your array is an immutable, not a mutable array.

You can either use mutableCopy to create a mutable copy and then sort that copy, or use the NSArray method `sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:` (which operates on an immutable array, and returns a sorted version of the contents as a second immutable array.)

To use mutableCopy, your code might look like this:

```
- (NSMutableArray*) timeSortedBegins {
    NSMutableArray* begins = [[self.spans valueForKey: @"begin"] mutableCopy];
    NSSortDescriptor *sort = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey: @"cycleOffsetObject" ascending: YES];
    [begins sortUsingDescriptors: @[sort]];
    return begins;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Check that `[self.spans valueForKey: @"begin"]` is actually an `NSMutableArray` before casting it. The error message indicates that the pointer is actually an `NSArray`