# What is the easiest way to sort a NSMutableArray in obj C

Tags: ios, objective-c, sorting, nsmutablearray

I have code as follows:

```
-(NSInteger) sortList:(NSMutableArray*)list {
    if(!list)
        return -1;

    //sort list
     [list sortUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];

   //do other stuff

}
```

My code constantly crashes with `*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSArrayI sortUsingSelector:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance`

The list is not empty and definitely contains some elements. So I have no idea why it is crashing. I instead tried to use this piece of code instead for comparision

```
 [list sortUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id  obj1, id obj2) {
            NSNumber *num1 = obj1;
            NSNumber *num2 = obj2;

        if([num1 integerValue] <= [num2 integerValue]){
                return NSOrderedAscending;
            } 
        else
            return NSOrderedDescending;
    }];
```

Also crashes with the same issue. Any idea what I might be doing wrong here?

Comment: That means that your array is in fact an *immutable* `NSArray` ...

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22570144/baffled-by-nsmutablearray-sortusingdescriptors-exception.

Comment: Your title doesn't match your question.

Comment: @MartinR Thanks for the tip.  I had an array of arrays. The outer array was NSMutable but the internal one was NSArray type and I had failed to notice that. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work for me, but it doesn't sort inline, rather returns the sorted list:

```
-(NSArray *) sortList:(NSMutableArray*)list {

    NSMutableArray *copy = [list mutableCopy];

    [copy sortUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id  _Nonnull num1, id  _Nonnull num2) {
            if([num1 integerValue] <= [num2 integerValue]){
                return NSOrderedAscending;
            }
            else
                return NSOrderedDescending;

    return copy;
}
```

Comment: Good idea to make the param mutable, but the OP ought to discover why the param she/he thinks is mutable sometimes isn't.   Moreover, once you know that you have a mutable copy, `respondsToSelector:@selector(sortUsingComparator:)` is superfluous.

Comment: Also, the `nil` check is superfluous.

Comment: Why convert `NSNumber` into `integer` to do the compare, and not use directly `compare:`? `return [num1 compare:num2]` if OP still wants to use comparator?